# HBase error while the installation on the VM

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I try to install hbase on the vm but without success. I follow this article: https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#quickstart.

My steps were:
1. Install CentOS 7 minimal.
2. Download hbase.
3. Download and install Java 8.
4. Set JAVA_HOME variable with value : /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre
5. edit conf/hbase-site.xml with the following text:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/testuser/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/testuser/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

6. start hbase:
sh bin/start-hbase.sh

7.connect to hbase:
./bin/hbase shell

After 7 case I have got the error:

```
2016-07-05 22:25:27,810 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-07-05 22:25:54,791 ERROR [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 4 attempts
2016-07-05 22:25:54,793 WARN  [main] zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection-0x205765570x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:541)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:880)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:636)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:450)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeStaticDirect(JavaMethod.java:362)
        at org.jruby.java.invokers.StaticMethodInvoker.call(StaticMethodInvoker.java:58)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
        at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
        at org.jruby.ast.InstAsgnNode.interpret(InstAsgnNode.java:95)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:169)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:191)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:302)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:144)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
        at org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:822)
        at org.jruby.RubyClass$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$i$newInstance.gen:65535)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:249)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
        at home.alex.hbase_minus_1_dot_1_dot_5.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.__file__(/home/alex/hbase-1.1.5/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:118)
        at home.alex.hbase_minus_1_dot_1_dot_5.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.load(/home/alex/hbase-1.1.5/bin/../bin/hirb.rb)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:697)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:690)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:597)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:446)
        at org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:369)
        at org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:258)
        at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:224)
        at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:208)
        at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:188)
2016-07-05 22:25:54,799 ERROR [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: hconnection-0x205765570x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:541)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:880)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:636)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:450)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeStaticDirect(JavaMethod.java:362)
        at org.jruby.java.invokers.StaticMethodInvoker.call(StaticMethodInvoker.java:58)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
        at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
        at org.jruby.ast.InstAsgnNode.interpret(InstAsgnNode.java:95)
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:169)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:191)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:302)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:144)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
        at org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:822)
        at org.jruby.RubyClass$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$i$newInstance.gen:65535)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:249)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
        at home.alex.hbase_minus_1_dot_1_dot_5.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.__file__(/home/alex/hbase-1.1.5/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:118)
        at home.alex.hbase_minus_1_dot_1_dot_5.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.load(/home/alex/hbase-1.1.5/bin/../bin/hirb.rb)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:697)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:690)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:597)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:446)
        at org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:369)
        at org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:258)
        at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:224)
        at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:208)
        at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:188)
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 1.1.5, r239b80456118175b340b2e562a5568b5c744252e, Sun May  8 20:29:26 PDT 2016

hbase(main):001:0>
```

Please, help me to figure out what I am missing.

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run hbase as standalone mode, but `HMaster` is not running.
Run `jps` to check and check the log to find the reason why it is down.

Comment: HMaster is running

Comment: that's weird... so can you get the pid of HMaster and see what ports it has opened ?